# ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

This question has been asked here before so please forgive me for asking again; the answers did not resolve my issue.

I'm working on a report interface that will run stored procedures from an Oracle database through my .NET application. We have 2 oracle database instances: **Dev** and **Stage**. I can connect to both Oracle databases from SQL Developer app and run stored procedures successfully.

The problem exists when I try to run report from the web UI that calls the **DEV** database. It breaks and returns Oracle errors telling me there are no records, but when I run the same report using the same Dev stored procedure and the database pointing to the **STAGE**, it returns data with no issues.

```
BEGIN
  -- <logic>Get current role</logic>
  SELECT GRANTED_ROLE
  INTO L_GRANTED_ROLE
  FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS
  WHERE GRANTED_ROLE LIKE 'XYZ_%';

  -- <logic>Retrieve the employee id</logic>
  L_EMPLOYEE_ID   := XYZ.UTILS.GET_EMPLOYEE_ID;
  -- <logic>Load course profile</logic>
  XYZ.UTILS.LOAD_EMP_TEACHING_PROFILE (P_COURSE_ID, NULL);
```

Comment: What database user is your .NET application connecting to Oracle as? Is it the same account that you're using in SQL Developer? USER_ROLE_PRIVS returns different rows depending on what user you are.

Comment: @kfinity I am using different user accounts for the .NET app login, but I also used different user account for the Stage .NET app and it seems to work fine.

Comment: USER_ROLE_PRIVS is basically DBA_ROLE_PRIVS filtered by the current user, so why don't you take a look at that? I think you'll find that your .NET user was not granted an XYZ_% role in DEV, but your SQL Developer user does have it.

Answer (score 0):

So it is very simple. In stage db you must have data returned in following query and in dev, there is no data with following query:

```
SELECT GRANTED_ROLE
  --INTO L_GRANTED_ROLE
  FROM USER_ROLE_PRIVS
  WHERE GRANTED_ROLE LIKE 'XYZ_%';
```

Execute above query and you will find the issue by yourself.

You need to change the logic of your proc to handle such cases.

Cheers!!